# Devise - If User Deactivated, Show Page To Allow Them To Reactivate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've followed the tutorial on the following article for how to deactivate users:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user-when-user-deletes-account

My question is, how do I make it so that when a deactivated user signs in, it shows them a page that allows the to reactivate their account? IE: "users/reactivate" with a button to reactivate?

I know I have to rewrite the default Users sessions controller of course, but I'm not quite sure at what point or how active_for_authentication is called, and how I can overwrite the redirect.

Comment: please share a code snippet and the efforts you have made towards it.

Answer (score 0):

When a user attempts to log in, the request is routed to the `create` method of your `sessions_controller.rb`, where a session for this user is created if credentials are valid. Within that method, you just need to check whether the `deleted_at`column is populated, followed by some branching logic to either redirect to whatever landing page you have for valid logins or your reactivation page.

Your code would look something like the following sample, but again, you didn't provide implementation details, so it falls to you to adapt:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      unless user.deleted_at.nil?
        my_user_login_method
        redirect_to user # or redirect to a dashboard/landing page/whatever
      else
        render 'reactivate' # this would be a view for your reactivation page
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```